# I want to remove the www from url on https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove the www from https url by .htaccess. 
for example

i want to change

**https://www.example.com/ to https://example.com/**

I have tried many rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    https://example.come/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But nothing work. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Will this respect whatever scheme was entered? E.g. `http://www.example.com` -> `http://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` -> `https://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if you are using X-Forwarding then try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```